# Is $\mathcal O_X(U)\cong \Bbb Z^i$ true?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathcal O_X$ the sheaf associated to the constant presheaf $\Bbb Z$. Given an open set $U$ of $X$, let $i$ denote the cardinal of components of $U$, is $\mathcal O_X(U)\cong \Bbb Z^i$ true?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, assuming that $X$ has finitely many component (or more generally that each connected component is open in $X$) since a continuous function $f : U \to \Bbb Z$ is constant on each connected component.

On the other hand, since you tagged "algebraic geometry", if $X$ is an algebraic variety with the Zariski topology, locally constant sheaves are not very interesting as Zariski open are too big (more precisely if $X$ is irreducible, every non-empty opens intersects). One solution is to use coherent sheaves, or change the topology and use the euclidean topology if you are working over $\Bbb C$ or $\Bbb R$ for example.

Also $\mathcal O_X$ is usually used for the structure sheaf, i.e the set of regular function $f : X \to k$.